# Testing custom react hook that calls another hook

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm having a dilemma when creating tests for my custom react hooks. (I'm  new to testing)

Basically, I have this hook useUpdateProfileName, which uses useSelectProfile hook that manages my profile's state (profile is an object), and the only thing that it does is to update the name of the currently selected profile.

```js
import { useSelectProfile } from './use-select-profile';

export const useUpdateProfileName = () => {
  const { selectedProfile, setSelectedProfile } = useSelectProfile();

  const updateName = (name: string) => {
    selectedProfile.name = name;
    setSelectedProfile(selectedProfile);
  };

  return { updateName };
};
```

How can I mock my useSelectProfile hook so that when I execute the updateName with a given string I can use selectedProfile to be validated?

```js
describe('Use Update Profile Name', () => {
  let profile: Profile;

  beforeAll(() => {
    profile = {name: 'Out of office'};
    
    wrapper = ({ children }) => {
      return (
        <ProfileStoreProvider>{children}</ProfileStoreProvider>
      );
    };
  });
  
  it('Should update profile name', () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useUpdateProfileName(), { wrapper });

    act(() => {
      //setSelectedProfile(profile);
      result.current.updateName('Online');
    });

    expect(selectedProfile).toHaveProperty('name', 'Online');
  });
});
```

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to mock the hook. You can just return `selectedName` from the `useUpdateProfileName` hook:

```
import { useSelectProfile } from './use-select-profile';

export const useUpdateProfileName = () => {
  const { selectedProfile, setSelectedProfile } = useSelectProfile();

  const updateName = (name: string) => {
    selectedProfile.name = name;
    setSelectedProfile(selectedProfile);
  };

  return { updateName, selectedProfile };
};
```

And then in your test, you should be able to make the assertion on `result.current.selectedProfile`:

```
  it("Should update profile name", () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useUpdateProfileName(), { wrapper });

    act(() => {
      result.current.updateName("Online");
    });

    expect(result.current.selectedProfile).toHaveProperty("name", "Online");
  });
```